# Does $f\in C^1$ Implies $f\in C$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Does the fact that the partial derivates are continuous and therefore the function is differentiable we can conclude that the function is continuous (differentiability $\rightarrow$ continuity )?

Comment: Yes, for sure. It does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\|f(x+h)-f(x)\|\leq\|h\|^{-1}\|f(x+h)-f(x)-Df(x)h\|\|h\|+\|Df(x)\|\|h\|\rightarrow 0$, so $f$ is continuous at $x$.